# What is the best way of implementing App Transport Security?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, nsapptransportsecurity

I'm making a web browser and I'm in the process of finalizing the application and submitting it to the app store.

One of the things I left for last is App Transport Security.

I know it's forced so Developers use https:// instead of http:// but a web browser can't be limited like this.

Is there anything else I can do besides adding "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads: YES" to the info.plist file?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For iOS 10+, you can evaluate using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia`,
  `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`,
  `NSRequiresCertificateTransparency` or 
  `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` instead of the *highly* insecure `ArbitraryLoads: YES`.
- However, for a `web browser` application, I don't see much of an alternative besides `ArbitraryLoads: YES`. You can consider implementing alerting the user when loading such sites.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) is the complete guide to `ATS`

Comment: I have to use iOS 9.0 in order to cover 95% user adoption.